# Ember Component does not get model change

Tags: ember.js

I'm relatively new to Ember.js and there are some things I dont really get so far. I use a component in my template and I pass in a model and a value. The value is used to filter the model (I also need the whole model, so i cant pass in the filtered version). When i first render it, everything is fine, but if I change the passed in value, the component empties the part, that relies on the model (hard to explain;))

index.hbs:

```
{{#content-view contents=contents parentId=sectionId}}{{/content-view}}
```

component.hbs:

```
<h1>Content</h1>
<p>{{parentId}}</p> //this part changes correctly
{{#each filteredContents as |fContent|}} //this part gets empty on change of parentId
    <p>{{fContent.type}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

component.js:

```
filteredContents: function() {
    return this.get('contents').filterBy('parentId', this.get('parentId'));
}.property('parentId')
```

As far as I get it now, the parentId is passed in correctly, and the first time the component is called, `filteredContent` also behaves correcty, but as soon as I change the parentId, there seems to be something wrong.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a case where the new `parentId` isn't matching a parentId of the contents? I just created a quick dummy app and it worked as expected on change. As an aside, you should use `.property('parentId', 'contents')` since the property relies on both attributes. Can you log 'contents' and 'parentId' inside your computed property and verify that runs when `parentId` changes?

Comment: You should even use `.property('parentId', 'contents.@each.parentId')` if the `parentId` may change, or simply `.property('parentId', 'contents.[]')` if it may not.

Comment: I finally figured out why it didnt work. I parse the parentId through a function, and somehow, i dont know where, it is changed into a string (I never thought this could be the mistake). Guess I just thought it had to be my lack of knowledge in ember. And now I learnd, that if i get a value out of the model, it does not stay the same type of data ;)